# Sitecore xDB Data Migration Tool is not compatible for Sitecore 9.2

Tags: sitecore-client

I downloaded and installed Sitecore 9.2 fresh instance from https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Experience_Platform/92/Sitecore_Experience_Platform_92_Initial_Release.aspx. 
Now I also downloaded "Sitecore xDB Data Migration Tool" packages from the same link. When I tried to install "Data Exchange Framework" package, I am getting error

*Could not load type 'Sitecore.Jobs.JobOptions' from assembly 'Sitecore.Kernel, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.*

Do anybody know workaround for this or compatible Sitecore xDB Data Migration Tool module available for Sitecore 9.2?

Comment: I guess data exchange framework is not compatible with 9.2 :)

Comment: But Sitecore have listed "Sitecore xDB Data Migration Tool" on the same 9.2 download page. How will developers migrate earlier version of Sitecore to 9.2 then?

Comment: @SurenderA It is mention clearly in the above mentioned url "Sitecore xDB Data Migration Tool -- Convert and migrate data from Sitecore Experience Database 8.x to Sitecore Experience Database 9.1."

Comment: This seems wrong... I am trying to ask around internally on this.

Comment: Haven't gotten an update, but apparently there is a dependency on DEF for 9.2 which has not been released yet.

Comment: I'm having the same error on a Fresh 9.2 install. Only other thing installed is SPE 5.0

Comment: Same thing here when trying to install the Sitecore Connect CRM for Salesforce 2.1.

Comment: @JasonSt-Cyr do you know if there's a patch available? kinda dead in the water until something is released unless there's another work around.

Comment: If you have an immediate need, you should contact support. I believe DEF for 9.2 (which underpins a bunch of connectors) is still not released.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The xDB migration tool for 9.2 is now available (https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_xDB_Data_Migration_Tool/3x/xDB_Data_Migration_Tool_300.aspx)

The original issue occurred because at the time of the 9.2 release, the required packages had not yet been released for xDB data migration. All of the connectors are released in batches after the main platform so there was a delay between initial availability of the platform for 9.2 and the connectors/migration tools.